# RadDataForm not show up on first draw

Tags: forms, nativescript, nativescript-angular

**SOLUTION (update 2019-10-21):**

It looks that I must add one import statement in my login.module.ts:

```
import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";
```

After that problem was solved and my form is displayed every time.

---

Project is in NativeScript 6 with Angular 8.

I have a simple login form with two fields (email and password). Form is displayed after default redirect if user is not logged in before.

The problem is that my RadDataForm is not displayed until I do "redraw" eg. by jump to "Register" view and back to "Login" view.

Some code:

login.component.html:

```
<ScrollView>
    <DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
        // ...
        <GridLayout columns="*,*,*,*,*" rows="*,*,*,*,*">
            <Label colSpan="5" row="0" [text]="row 0"></Label>
            <RadDataForm 
              col="1" 
              colSpan="3" 
              row="1" 
              tkLoginForm 
              tkToggleNavButton 
              [source]="loginForm" 
              [metadata]="metadata"
            ></RadDataForm>
            // rest elements in grid
        </GridLayout>
    </DockLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

There is no errors in console. Form source is ok. Form metadata is ok.

I trying to put form in separate layout (Stack, Grid, Dock), withour layout, set width and/or height in CSS and inline. Still nothing.

I have exactly same code on "Register" view and there is no problem with displaying form. Even when I change the redirection to the "Register" view.

Some screens:

[image: No form]
[image: With form]

Comment: Try removing the ScrollView and see if the form will render as expected. If the ScrollView removal is fixing the issue then you will need to assign a height to your container layout (e.g. the DockLayout) - you could say something like `height="100%"`

Comment: Thanks for tip but it wasn't help but I found a solution. In login.module.ts there must be an import statement (and in imports array in module declaration):
`import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";`.
Just adding those import fix my problem. Maybe this module should be reqiured and should throw some error if it isn't imported?

Comment: The import of this module is not mandatory. It should be used only if you need two-way Angular binding. This is the reason why when the import is missing there is no error message